# Need to find the diameter of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I got a question on my assignment and I'm really not sure where to start or even what some of these graphs are so I'm hoping someone will be able to help me.

> I need to find the diam of $K_{n}$, $P_{n}$, $C_{n}$ and $B_{3}$.

Comment: I think you'd better find out exactly what these graphs are then. How about consulting whoever it was who set this assignment?

Comment: Well I know what Kn and CN are but i'm not sure about the other 2

Comment: $K_n$ denotes the [complete graph on $n$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph).  $C_n$ denotes the [cycle graph on $n$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph).  $P_n$ denotes the [path graph on $n$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph).  As for $B_3$, that is not a notation I'm familiar with but if it is appearing in an assignment you have been given then it should have been defined either in your textbook, in your notes, or sometime during your lectures.  As for diameter [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Diameter is the longest possible distance between two vertices in the graph, and should be almost immediately recognizable for each of the examples.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. By the definition you've given me I would say that 
Diam (Pn) =n-1
Diam (Kn) = n-1
Diam (Cn)= n-1

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke or you misunderstood me.  Diameter is not the longest length of a path between two vertices.  Diameter is the maximum of the set of shortest distances between vertices.  In $K_n$ although between two vertices there exists a path of length $n-1$ there is a much shorter path simply of length $1$ between them.

Comment: Okay, So in Kn since everything is connected, this will be 1. In Cn the diameter will be (n-1)/2 and in Pn it will be n-1?

Comment: Closer, you have an error for $C_n$, noting that when $n$ is even the number you suggest isn't an integer.  Otherwise, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much! You just answered my first question on this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The distance between two vertices is the length of the shortest path between them. The diameter is the longest distance in the graph.